# How to map pojo class's field to string object returning from API

Tags: java, gson

I am working on an application where I want to convert string object coming from data api to json object.Now, I converted string object to json but there is a problem.
My pojo class has multiple fields with corresponding getters and setters one of them is "filterName" and it looks like

```
   @SerializedName(value="cellFilter", alternate="tissueFilter")
    private String filterName;
```

What it does is it extracts the value associated with "cellFilter" and "tissueFilter". I am not sure if its an optimized way to retire the data using the same field. Also, I want to use that same field to retrieve another value and I don't know how to do that ( i.e I want to use filterName to get the values of tissueFilter, cellFilter and applicationFilter ).

data object looks like as following
Note - there are 3 strings for tissueFilter, cellFilter and applicationFilter which comes from data api. After converting them in java objects they look like this,

tissufilter

```
 {
    "url": "xyz",
    "sortOrder": 8,
    "imageId": "1111",
    "tissueFilter": "Heart"
  }
```

cellFilter

```
{
    "url": "xyz",
    "sortOrder": 6,
    "imageId": "2222",
    "cellFilter": "Pancreas"
  }
```

and applicationFilter

```
 {
    "applicationFilter": "c56",
    "url": "xyz",
    "sortOrder": 1,
    "imageId": "3333",
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Jackson JSON library is used for serializing/deserialing JSON data, `@JsonAlias` annotation should be applied to deserialize the field which may have different names:

```java
@Data
class Pojo {
    private String url;
    private int orderId;
    private String imageId;

    @JsonAlias({"applicationFilter", "cellFilter", "tissueFilter"})
    private String filter;
}
```

After deserialization of the mentioned JSON snippets, the field `filter` should be set to appropriate value defined as `"applicationFilter"`, etc.

---

However, it seems that Gson is used in the question, and its `@SerializedName` also allows for multiple versions in `alternate` parameter:

```java
@Data
class PojoForGson {
    private String url;
    private int orderId;
    private String imageId;

    @SerializedName(value = "cellFilter" alternate = {"applicationFilter",  "tissueFilter"})
    private String filter;
}
```